# How to align labels and buttons inline and

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm learning front-end development by myself and I'm trying build a simple MyAccount page using React and styled-components. I want to create a simple layout with labels and buttons like this (but prettier of course):

[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVdfq.png)

[This is the current situation of the label and the buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVdfq.png)

Here is the myAccount codes:

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import styled, {createGlobalStyle} from 'styled-components'
import ClearIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Clear';
import css from '../components/css/MyAccount.css'

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');
body {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}`


function MyAccount(props) {
    return(
        <>
            <GlobalStyle></GlobalStyle>
            <div className='MyAccount'>
                <div className='CloseButton1'>
                    <ClearIcon fontSize='large' onClick={props.onClose}></ClearIcon>
                </div>
                <label>Email</label>
                <Button>Edit</Button>
                <label>Username</label>
                <Button>Edit</Button>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

const Button = styled.button`
    color: #000;
    background-color: #00FF60;
    font-size: 1em;
    border: 2px solid #00ff60;
    border-radius: 8px;
    height:10%;
    width:10%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;

    &:hover {
        background-color: #16161b;
        color: #f1f1f1;
        border-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
`;

export default MyAccount
```

Label has its own css (right now it is empty as I have no idea how to do what I'm trying to do) in MyAccount.css and here it is:

```css
.MyAccount{
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    top:10%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    left:15%;
    border-radius: 12px;
    z-index: 1200;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 9999px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    background: #0b0b0b;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.label{
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1680px) {
    .MyAccount{
        left: 25%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1680px) {
    .MyAccount{
        left: 560px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Both images are same.

Comment: Sorry, fxed it.

Comment: Try this - `<div><label><button></div>  <div><label><button> </div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to think of this as boxes, email box and user box, the boxes would be divs, inside each div you'd have the two components (label and button) the divs by themselfs will have a "display:block" property, which will make them take the whole row, the components inside each div need to be "display:inline" (of course talking basics)

so:

```
<div>
    <label style="display:inline">Email</label>
    <button style="display:inline">make your thing</button>
</div>
```

Both like this will show them as you want, however, you should google "flex-box" which will make everything more responsive and easier ;)

Comment: Thank you so much Gabriel! I will.